# Custom surround template

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

How can I define my own custom surround template that I can use to wrap around a selection of javascript code followed by reformat.

[image]

I've used `Alt + Cmd + T` to bring up this option panel.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Go to Settings/Live Templates, create a new Live template, specify abbreviation, description and contexts, check *Reformat according to code style*.

And now the important part. The Live template content must contain `$SELECTION$` variable for it to be applicable for Surround with action. For instance:

```
console.log($SELECTION$);
```

After you save the template you should see it in the pop-up list next time you use the *Surround With* action.

Comment: Can't wait to make this for `System.out.println($SELECTION$);`

Comment: If the content already has a semicolon on it, is there any way to get intellij to move it to the end/delete it?

Comment: Sweeeeeeeeeeeet !

Comment: Note you may have to restart Intellij to see the change in the Surround with... menu (I did.)