# Use an expression as argument for another expression in IntelliJ editor

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have an expression in java:

```
str.trim()
```

and I would like to "transform" it to:

```
myFunction(str.trim())
```

The only things I would like physically do are:

1. Select the initial expression
2. Press the magic key
3. just write "myFunction" (I would not type the parenthesis, or move the caret at all, and ideally I would get a suggestion upon ctrl+space for myFunction).

Is it possible? (live templates did not help)

EDIT: This question was marked as a duplicate of [Custom surround template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28438521/custom-surround-template) which is not the case, since the specific question describes how to create a live template for a a specific surround, eg console.log($SELECTION$). My question is more generic, as I do not want to define a live template for each and every case, but something the will work anywhere, anytime, within of course the editing context.

Comment: Live templates do actually help; see linked question for more information.

Comment: @yole Please review the last edit, where I explain why I do not consider live templates and the referred question as a solution.

Comment: Live templates can contain variables. You can define a variable in your live template that will hold the name of the function to call.

Comment: Yes, but the variable will be the $SELECTION. What will be around the selection should be statically defined in the template. I do not want to statically define that. I want to be able to use anything valid within the context there. This is the reason I do not consider the question duplicate.

Comment: No. You can define multiple variables - one for $SELECTION$ and the other for the function name.

Comment: @yole I honestly cannot see how this could work. Somebody could have answered the question if it was not marked as duplicate. Perhaps you can provide a concrete example?

Comment: Concrete example: define a live template as $FUNCTION$($SELECTION$), press "Edit variables", enter "complete()" as expression for $FUNCTION$, select your piece of code, press "Surround with live template", select your template.